# how to pass the selected row id in a grid view value to a redirection url

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview to display request information from a table.
I have added a button template feild which upon clicking should take the user to the appropriate request url

How do i capture the selected requestid and pass it on as a variable in my redirection url

**My gridview**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="roc_id" DataSourceID="analystdefaultview" 
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True"  
    AllowSorting="True" Visible="False" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>

               <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton = "true"  />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RequestId" SortExpression="roc_id">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("roc_id") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Button ID = "button2" runat = "server" Text='<%# Bind("roc_id") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fundtype" HeaderText="fundtype" 
            SortExpression="fundtype" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="productionmth" HeaderText="productionmth" 
            SortExpression="productionmth" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="targetdt" HeaderText="targetdt" 
            SortExpression="targetdt" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="actualdt" HeaderText="actualdt" 
            SortExpression="actualdt" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="freqcd" HeaderText="freqcd" 
            SortExpression="freqcd" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="entereddt" HeaderText="entereddt" 
            SortExpression="entereddt" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="groupcnt" HeaderText="groupcnt" 
            SortExpression="groupcnt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rptrsrcetxt" HeaderText="rptrsrcetxt" 
            SortExpression="rptrsrcetxt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="dateavailable" HeaderText="dateavailable" 
            SortExpression="dateavailable" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="groupname" HeaderText="groupname" 
            SortExpression="groupname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="groupnbr" HeaderText="groupnbr" 
            SortExpression="groupnbr" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="datarecpdet" HeaderText="datarecpdet" 
            SortExpression="datarecpdet" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>






<asp:SqlDataSource ID="analystdefaultview" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Underwriting %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT
       [roc_id]
       ,[fundtype]
       ,Convert(varchar(20),[prodmth],111) as productionmth
       ,Convert(varchar(20),[targetdt],111) as targetdt
       ,Convert(varchar(20),[actualdt],111) as actualdt
       ,[freqcd]
       ,Convert(varchar(20),[entereddt],111) as entereddt
       ,[groupcnt]
       ,[rptrsrcetxt]     
       ,Convert(varchar(20),[date_available],111) as dateavailable
       ,[groupname]
       ,[groupnbr]
       ,[datarecpdet]


        from renoffcyc where opa_id = @opaid and YEAR(prodmth) = YEAR(getdate()) AND MONTH(prodmth) = MONTH(getdate())"

     DeleteCommand = "DElete from renoffcyc where  roc_id = @roc_id" >


    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="chooseanalyst" DefaultValue="1" Name="opaid" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
```

**.cs file** - The roc_id is the variable that i need to pass to the url

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://xxx.yahoo.com/testing/adhoc/Edit.asp?ROCID=roc_id");

    }
```

Comment: I'm still looking for help on this as i was not able to resolve this isuue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [**RowCommand**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event, along with **[CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** for passing value in RowCommmand event.

**Html**

```
<ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Button ID = "button2" runat = "server" CommandName="cmdYourButtonPurpose" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("roc_id") %>'
                Text='<%# Bind("roc_id") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Code Behind**

```
void ContactsGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.CommandName=="cmdYourButtonPurpose")
     {   
         Response.Redirect("http://xxx.yahoo.com/testing/adhoc/Edit.asp?ROCID=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString(););
     }
}
```

Comment: it is doing nothing after i make the change as before whn i click on the button

Comment: Two-way binding is only supported for properties. 'CommandArguments' is not a valid property on 'Button'

Comment: I think the error is due to typing mistake in asp:Button, I had typed CommandArguments instead of CommandArgument. Now corrected, give it a try. As asp:Button support CommandArgument http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
protected void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
     GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;   
     string roc_id = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].ToString();

     string url = String.Format("http://xxx.yahoo.com/testing/adhoc/Edit.asp?ROCID={0}", roc_id);
     Response.Redirect(url);   
}
```

Comment: getting this error Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataKey' to 'string'

Source Error:

 

Line 67:      GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
Line 68: 
Line 69:    string roc_id = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex];
Line 70: 
Line 71:          Response.Redirect("http://cfs-dev.uhc.com/cfsunderwriting/custrpt/adhoc/Tracking/Offcycles/Edit.asp?ROCID= + roc_id");

Comment: Iam using the below and it does not redirect protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        string roc_id = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].ToString();

        string url = String.Format("http://xxx.yahoo.com/testing/adhoc/Tracking/Offcycles/Edit.asp?ROCID={0}", roc_id);
        Response.Redirect(url);   


    }